# Expo Application Services (eas) upload release notes

Tags: android, ios, expo

We are thinking of using Expo Application Services to build and then submit our builds to both app store and the play store.

All seems pretty straightforward, however, there is one piece that we can't figure out, how do you submit with the build the release notes.

Is there some flag we can use like this `eas submit -p android --profile foobar --release-note release.txt` ?

Comment: I would like to do the same, did you figure out a solution?

Comment: Also interested in this

Comment: in 2024 and am also still wondering this -- does anyone ever figure out how to automate this?

Comment: still waiting on this feature, I just don't get how this is not a thing yet...